Connection hangs at password
Basic question: I want to connect 2 systems (A and B, on different networks) to a single mysql database. No problem with the 1st one, but the 2nd one hangs at the password:
A $ mariadb -v --protocol=tcp -P 3318 -h pptest04.in2p3.fr -u myowndb -p -D myowndb
Enter password: 
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 8962583
Server version: 10.6.8-MariaDB-log Source distribution
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.
Reading history-file /home/centos/.mysql_history
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
MariaDB [myowndb]> QUIT
Writing history-file /home/centos/.mysql_history
Bye


B $ nc -zv pptest04.in2p3.fr 3318
Connection to pptest04.in2p3.fr 3318 port [tcp/sdt-lmd] succeeded!

B $ telnet pptest04.in2p3.fr 3318
Trying pptest04.in2p3.fr...
Connected to pptest04.in2p3.fr.
Escape character is '^]'.
\
5.5.5-10.6.8-MariaDB-log���";F,Ik^v�V,u-~ScxSuujmysql_native_passwordkAxg1456cSW4A22P
!#08S01Got packets out of orderConnection closed by foreign host.

B $ mariadb -v --protocol=tcp -P 3318 -h pptest04.in2p3.fr -u myowndb -p -D myowndb
Enter password: 
[...hangs...]

What could cause this ? If it was a firewall, nc and telnet would fail. I'm no SQL expert, but I doubt it's an SQL problem either...

Maybe because telnet and nc are different? See: What is the difference between telnet and netcat? (Superuser.com)

Which is why I've tried both. But it doesn't explain the difference in behavior between both mariadb clients...
